# BeautifulSoup not parsing past the title tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse a page

http://gwyneddathletics.com/custompages/sport/mlacrosse/stats/2014/ml0402gm.htm

and when I try to findAll('b') I get no results, same with 'tr'. I cannot find anything beyond the initial title tag.

Also, when I do soup = BeautifulSoup(markup)  and print the soup, I get the entire page with an extra  at the end of the output

I am using python 2.6 with BeautifulSoup 3.2.0. Why is my soup not parsing the page correctly?

Comment: can you share the code you use to read the content?

Comment: req = urllib2.Request(url)  response = urllib2.urlopen(req)  markup = response.read()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely the parser that BeautifulSoup is using really doesn't like the markup on the page, I have had similar issues happen in the past. I did a quick test on your input and found that if you upgrade to the newest BeautifulSoup (the package is called bs4) it *just works*. bs4 also supports python2.6 and the backwards incompatible changes between it and BeautifulSoup (the 3.x series) are tiny. See [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#porting-code-to-bs4) if you need to check out how to port.